# How to add tooltip on top of font-awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome, ng-bootstrap

I recently upgraded my font-awesome and ng-bootstrap, after which the tooltip has stopped working. Here's the code-

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle px-1" aria-hidden="true" [ngbTooltip]="'Tooltip which shows on top'"></i>
```

The same code was working earlier before the update. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Update:
I enclosed the `<i>` tag with a span tag and put the ngbTooltip directive in span tag only. It works with this "hack"!

Comment: I'm assuming you've upgraded to V6, the classes have been changed so you're required to add the full name of the type of font you want. e.g change <i class="fa fa-info-circle"> to <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>. In this case : "fa-solid" is what you should use instead. Read more [here](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/get-started)

Answer (score 0):

This should not be that hard have you tried the way Angular Bootstrap shows?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary me-2" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle px-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Looks like you missing placement?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yeah I already tried this, and it works as well but the thing is that I wanted the tooltip to appear when I hover over the icon and not the button.